# libWebscokets server with SSL dont enter PEM pass phrase

Tags: c++, websocket

I try to develop webscoket server with ssl, using libwebsockets library.

Could I hardcode PEM pass phrase in my code?
I read all documentation for libwebsockets but i can not found this.
It is code for creation websocket server:

```
struct lws_context_creation_info info;
memset(&info, 0, sizeof info);
info.port = 7681;
info.iface = interface1;
info.protocols = protocols;
info.ssl_cert_filepath = cert_path;
info.ssl_private_key_filepath = key_path;
info.ssl_cert_filepath = "./file.pem";
info.ssl_private_key_filepath ="./file.key.pem";

info.gid = -1;
info.uid = -1;
info.options = opts;

context = libwebsocket_create_context(&info);
```

I run program and i need to enter PEM pass phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use OpenSSL, there are two ways to set SSL context on libwebsockets session.(libwebsockets v2.0)

1. You can make your own SSL_CTX structure using OpenSSL APIs.

   `SSL_CTX* ssl_ctx;`

   `/* set up ssl_ctx using OpenSSL APIs including below. */`
   `SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata(ssl_ctx, "passphrase");`
   `SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(ssl_ctx, callback_function);`

   `// ...`

   `info.provided_ssl_ctx = ssl_ctx;`

   By this way you can customize SSL context as you want. But if provided_ssl_ctx set not NULL, libwebsockets does not take any responsibility about ssl_ctx. So you have to free the structure after whole process.

2. Make libwebsockets set SSL_CTX in its own process.

   `info.ssl_private_key_password = "passphrase";`

   If you want to modify more about SSL_CTX, you can do it in libwebsockets callback function on reason   LWS_CALLBACK_OPENSSL_LOAD_EXTRA_SERVER_VERIFY_CERTS. SSL_CTX will be passed to the callback function as `user` variable